# Reinforcement Learning on real time data over a web server

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, dataset, reinforcement-learning

**Question:** is it possible to implement a reinforcement learning model over a NodeJS server?

This server would be receiving binary forms of data (open /close; yes/no) in real time.

The objective for the model is to learn from the incoming data for a few days and then predict values for next day (similar to time series, but not exactly). The learned parameters need to be flushed every week.

Note: the training data I have doesn't allow for supervised learning - i.e. there is no data for the target class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - You need to define an Agent, Environment, State, and Rewards:

Agent - The current week process.
Environment - Server.
State - Current data.
Rewards - Predicted future values are the same observed values.

Then implement in JavaScript. One JavaScript framework is [REINFORCEjs](https://github.com/karpathy/reinforcejs)